# Remove incomplete days / retain complete days

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data from field instruments where values for 7 different parameters are measured and recorded every 15 minutes.  The data set extends for many years.  Sometimes the instruments fail or are taken off-line for preventive maintenance giving incomplete days in the record.  In post-processing the data, I would like to remove those incomplete days (or, stated alternatively, retain only the complete days).

An abbreviated example of what the data might look like:

```
Date                   Temp
2012-02-01 00:01:00    18.5
2012-02-01 00:16:00    18.4
2012-02-01 00:31:00    18.6
.
.
.
2012-02-01 23:31:00    19.0
2012-02-01 23:46:00    18.9
2012-02-02 00:01:00    19.0
2012-02-02 00:16:00    19.0
2012-02-03 00:01:00    17.0
2012-02-03 00:16:00    17.1
2012-02-03 00:31:00    17.0
.
.
.
2012-02-03 23:31:00    18.0
2012-02-03 23:46:00    18.2
```

So `2012-02-01` and `2012-02-03` are complete days and I'd like to remove `2012-02-02` as it is an incomplete day.

Comment: Do the complete days have a set number of observations (roughly 96)?

Comment: Yes, a complete day should have 96 observations (lines) per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date.rle = rle(df$Date)
Date.good = Date.rle$val[Date.rle$len==96]
df = df[df$Date %in% Date.good,]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert dates to days
2. Count the number of observations per day
3. Retain only those days with the maximum number of observations

The code

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dataset %>%
   mutate(Day = floor_date(Date, unit = "day")) %>%
   group_by(Day) %>%
   mutate(nObservation = n()) %>%
   filter(nObservation == max(nObservation)
```

Comment: I believe `filter(nObservation == max(nObservation))` does not work. You need to replace `max(nObservation)` with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R method that should work:

```
# create a day variable
df$day <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

# calculate the number of observations per day
df$obsCnt <- ave(df$Temp, df$day, FUN=length)

# subset data: more than 90 observations
dfNew <- df[df$obsCnt > 96,]
```

I put the threshold at 96 observations a day, but it is easily adjusted.